# Separation of cost from percentage complete?

Tags: scheduling

I am monitoring the progression of a mine shaft.

I have 2 goals each month:

- Goal 1: Progress 247 feet per month
- Goal 2: Spend roughly $133k per month. However, spend is not solely driven by the depth achieved

Thus, I’d like to monitor the "work complete %" (i.e. the mine depth). But if I only achieve 74% of depth target that month, I don’t want it to calculate 74% of the money for that month.

What would be the best or easiest way to enter these monthly tasks?

I also need the dates to shift accordingly, if the 247 feet per month target is not achieved in the previous month.

Comment: It might help people to provide effective answers if you quote which scheduling tool you are using...

Comment: Welcome to PMSE, William. Have you taken a look at Earned Value Management? EVM separates out amount spent from work accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of progress:  physical % complete, work % complete, and duration % complete.  Physical measurement is against the product itself and quantifies what you have completed as compared to the total product.  Work measurement is how many hours have been exhausted compared to total number of hours predicted.  And the duration measurement is number of work days exhausted compared to the total number of work days predicted.

It sounds like you are looking for a physical % complete, not work % complete.  If you need your dates to shift based on performance, you need to also assess your duration % complete.